# I am currently trying to implement a rudimentary firewall from a video I watched but the nimda worm detection is not working and i do not know why?

Tags: python, security, network-programming, firewall, kali-linux

ok so let me begin with the video in cause: https://youtu.be/wReXqe8AFUM?si=%5C_Lm-5DwvffglCYLL

**my setup**

- 1 Oracle VM running Kali Linux with normal settings except bridge adaptor for the network Settings
- IP Address: 192.168.0.24
- This VM runs my firewall.py with Visual Studio Code inside a venv
- 1 Oracle VM running Kali Linux with normal settings except bridge adaptor for the network Settings
- IP Address: 192.168.0.80
- This VM runs my nimda_attack.py with Code - OSS

**The code for the firewall.py**

```
import os
    import sys
    import time
    from collections import defaultdict
    from scapy.all import sniff, IP, TCP
    
    THRESHOLD = 40
    print(f"THRESHOLD: {THRESHOLD}")
    
    # Read IPs from a file
    def read_ip_file(filename):
        with open(filename, "r") as file:
            ips = [line.strip() for line in file]
        return set(ips)
    
    # Check for Nimda worm signature
    def is_nimda_worm(packet):
        if packet.haslayer(TCP) and packet[TCP].dport == 80:
            payload = packet[TCP].payload
            return "GET /scripts/root.exe" in str(payload)
        return False
    
    # Log events to a file
    def log_event(message):
        log_folder = "logs"
        os.makedirs(log_folder, exist_ok=True)
        timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", time.localtime())
        log_file = os.path.join(log_folder, f"log_{timestamp}.txt")
        
        with open(log_file, "a") as file:
            file.write(f"{message}\n")
    
    def packet_callback(packet):
        src_ip = packet[IP].src
    
          # Check if IP is in the whitelist
        if src_ip in whitelist_ips:
            return
    
        # Check if IP is in the blacklist
        if src_ip in blacklist_ips:
            os.system(f"iptables -A INPUT -s {src_ip} -j DROP")
            log_event(f"Blocking blacklisted IP: {src_ip}")
            return
        
          # Check for Nimda worm signature
        if is_nimda_worm(packet):
            print(f"Blocking Nimda source IP: {src_ip}")
            os.system(f"iptables -A INPUT -s {src_ip} -j DROP")
            log_event(f"Blocking Nimda source IP: {src_ip}")
            return
    
        packet_count[src_ip] += 1
    
        current_time = time.time()
        time_interval = current_time - start_time[0]
    
        if time_interval >= 1:
            for ip, count in packet_count.items():
                packet_rate = count / time_interval
    
                if packet_rate > THRESHOLD and ip not in blocked_ips:
                    print(f"Blocking IP: {ip}, packet rate: {packet_rate}")
                    os.system(f"iptables -A INPUT -s {ip} -j DROP")
                    log_event(f"Blocking IP: {ip}, packet rate: {packet_rate}")
                    blocked_ips.add(ip)
    
            packet_count.clear()
            start_time[0] = current_time
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        if os.geteuid() != 0:
            print("This script requires root privileges.")
            sys.exit(1)
    
        # Import whitelist and blacklist IPs
        whitelist_ips = read_ip_file("whitelist.txt")
        blacklist_ips = read_ip_file("blacklist.txt")
    
        packet_count = defaultdict(int)
        start_time = [time.time()]
        blocked_ips = set()
    
        print("Monitoring network traffic...")
        sniff(filter="ip", prn=packet_callback)
```

**The code for the nimda_attack.py**

```
from scapy.all import IP, TCP, Raw, send
    
    def send_nimda_packet(target_ip, target_port=80, source_ip="192.168.0.80", source_port=12345):
        try:
            packet = (
                IP(src=source_ip, dst=target_ip)
                / TCP(sport=source_port, dport=target_port)
                / Raw(load="GET /scripts/root.exe HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n")
            )
            send(packet, verbose=True)  # Set verbose=True to enable verbose output
        except Exception as e:
            print("An error occurred:", e)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        target_ip = "192.168.0.24"  # Replace with the IP address of the target machine
    
        send_nimda_packet(target_ip)
```

The code seemed to be working for the man in the video but for some reason it does not work on my setup. I tried dropping the threshold to 1, sniffing TCP instead of IP for the nimda worm packet and its still not working. I ran the scripts with sudo and I have whitelist.txt and blacklist.txt in the same folder as the code for the firewall. If I missed something or I made a mistake in the implementation please let me know what I can do to fix it, I am a beginner that is trying to learn. Thank you for reading this and have a nice day!